# Kibana (elasticsearch visualization) - how add plot based on sub-string of field?

Tags: elasticsearch, data-visualization, kibana

I have a field in my logs called `json_path` containing data like `/nfs/abc/123/subdir/blah.json` and I want to create `count` plot on part of the string `abc` here, so the third chunk using the token `/`. I have tried all sorts of online answers, but they're all partial answers (nothing I can easily understand how to use or integrate). I've tried running POST/GET queries in the `Console`, which all failed due to syntax errors I couldn't manage to debug (they were complaining about newline control chars, when there were none that I could obviously see or see in a text editor explicitly showing control-characters). I also tried `Management -> Index Patterns -> Scripted Field` but after adding my code there, basically the whole Kibana crashed (stopped working temporarily) until I removed that `Scripted Field`.

All this elasticsearch and kibana stuff is annoyingly difficult, all the docs expect you to be an expert in their tool, rather than just an engineer needing to visualize some data.

I don't really want to add a new data field in my log-generation code, because then all my old logs will be unsupported (which have the relevant data, it just needs that bit of string processing before data viz). I know I could probably back-annotate the old logs, but the whole Kibana/elasticsearch experience is just frustrating and I don't use it enough to justify learning such detailed procedures (I actually learned a bunch of this stuff a year ago, and then promptly forgot it due to lack of use).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot plot on a sub string of a field unless you extract that sub string into a new field. I can understand the frustration in learning a new product but to be able to achieve what you want you need to have that sub string value in a new field. Scripted fields are generally used to modify a field. To be able to extract sub string from a field I’d recommend using Ingest Node processor like [grok processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/grok-processor.html). This will add a new field which you can use to plot in Kibana visualizations..